# .KMZ file (suddenly) not working anymore

Tags: google-maps, maps, kml, kmz

I've got a website where I display .kmz files. It works perfectly for a long time, but since a few weeks the kmz file is not displaying anymore (and I haven't changed anything). I tried to upload it again, but without success. The .kmz can be found:

http://www.bordspelstats.nl/try.kmz

It still works in Google Earth.

The code on the webpage is similar to this one:
http://jsfiddle.net/Shreerang/sxNy9/7/light/

```
    var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.bordspelstats.nl/try.kmz',
```

If you change the above link I get a gray square.. Can someone help me?

Comment: That [KMZ file](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.bordspelstats.nl/try.kmz) is returning a [KmlLayerStatus](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#KmlLayerStatus) of `INVALID_DOCUMENT`. Possible related issue: [Issue 9157: KML limitations in Google Maps API](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9157).

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps Javascript API v3 KmlLayer class is returning an error code of: `INVALID_DOCUMENT` for that kmz.

If I unzip the KMZ and look at the KML, the xsi: namespace is marked as invalid.

> The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" associated with an element type "Document" is not bound.

If I remove that, the [KML displays with geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/SO_20160119_try_schema.kml)

If I zip it back up it [still doesn't work with KmlLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/SO_20160119_try_schema.kmz) (still returns `INVALID_DOCUMENT`), but [still works with geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/SO_20160119_try_schema.kmz)

So a work around might be to use a third party parser (like [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/)), but it is a fairly large file so that probably won't be a good long term solution for performance reasons.

Might be related to [issue 9157](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9157) in the issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks for the information and solution! Can you tell me what is going to happen with the issue 9157? Is someone going to read that and trying to fix it or should I find another long term solution?